# Converts two 16 bits word to float in python

Tags: python, byte

I've written a script that reads from a modbus channel and returns tuples of words (16 bits). 
I need to translate them into decimal numbers, how can I do it?
I've been reviewing the 'struct' python package, however, I'm not sure how to use it to achieve this.

EDIT: 
I'll give an example. Following the documentation, (43H, C8H) should be translated into 400 (decimal).

However, the modbus package returns a python tuple of two integers, like (1000, 60450).

BR,

Comment: What is the type name of your word objects? Is it a built-in type?

Comment: Edited with an example.

Comment: Got a link to the documentation where it says (43H, C8H) should be translated into 400?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify so I assume you're storing each word as an ordinary integer. Consult the [format character table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) and choose a C type has a size of 2 bytes and has a suitable range for your words. "H" is appropriate for unsigned words. `pack` the two integers into a string using the chosen type. Then `unpack` that into a float.

```
import struct
t = (123, 456)
packed_string = struct.pack("HH", *t)
unpacked_float = struct.unpack("f", packed_string)[0]
print unpacked_float
#result: 7.34690863652e-38
```

You can reverse the procedure the same way - pack, then unpack.

```
print struct.unpack("HH", struct.pack("f", unpacked_float))
#result: (123,456)
```

---

Edit: an additional example.

```
>>> t = (1000, 60450)
>>> import struct
>>> packed_string = struct.pack("HH", *t)
>>> unpacked_float = struct.unpack("f", packed_string)[0]
>>> print unpacked_float
-7.83457718087e+26
>>> print struct.unpack("HH", struct.pack("f", unpacked_float))
(1000, 60450)
```

Comment: I've tried with this piece of code to translate the example given and it's not working.

Comment: Strange, works fine for me. If you're getting an error, what error are you getting? If you're getting output that's different from what you expect, what output are you getting, and what output do you expect to get?

Comment: That's the point. Following the example given in the problem (post-edited), (43H, C8H) should be translated into 400.
Since (43H, C8H) is (67, 200), this is not working, right?

Comment: Ok, I think we're going outside of my area of expertise here, because I don't know what "43H" is supposed to represent. It's not hexadecimal because that only goes up to F... Is it some kind of base 36 thing?

Comment: It's hexadecimal, 16 bits. A word is composed by 2 registers of 8 bits each. So each word is represented by two-digit hexadecimal number

Comment: The ''H" suffix means hex, 43H is the same a 0x43.  But, decimal 400 is 0x190.  So I don't know how 43H and C8H can map to 400.